# Two Transactions and LazyInitializationException behavior

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is is a normal behavior that when I fetch an entity with lazy loaded associations in a `@Transactional` service, and then further in the controller I call the same service with this entity (it creates a new transaction, because the first transaction has already been commited), that I get `LazyInitializationException`?

Sample controller code:

```
Entity entity = entityService.get(id)
...
<some data binding, etc>
...
entityService.validate(entity) <---  here I get LazyInitializationException
```

Is it an anti-pattern if I fetched the `Entity` again in the `validate` method?

Comment: It is detached and not reattached because you are running a transactional method, you will need to reattach it yourself.

Comment: Is making a JOIN FETCH query a solution at this point? So that the associations I use further would be eagerly loaded and the second transaction "would know" about it?
Unfortunately I don't know what you mean by detached and not reattached

Comment: As soon as the transaction ends the managed entities get detached from the entitymanager used to retrieve them (unless you use opensessioninview anti-pattern). It needs an `EntityManager` to retrieve lazy associations, hence to do that you would need to do `EntityManager.merge` or `EntityManager.refresh` before anything else to attach it again. Loading the needed relations is one option. Or move everything to a single transactional service method instead of doing it in the controller.